# Data frame not returning full tuplet content in Jupyter notebook

Tags: dataframe, tuples, jupyter

Currently programmed my code in Jupyter notebook where the function `learn.predict("xxx")` will return a tuple:
[image]
Point is i want to transpose the tuple but since `learn.predict("xxx")`. predict not working, i use `DataFrame(learn.predict("xxx")).transpose()` but as shown this doesnot return the full content of the tuple as shown by the `...` in `[tensor(0.0006), tensor(0.0284), tensor(0.0006...`:
[image]
Any idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html), this is a solution to your problem:

`pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)`

BTW, the content of your cell is too long and I don't see any convenient solution but printing it separately as you did in the first picture.